# finding the volume of a tethrahedron (course MIT 18.02 multivariate calculus)

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

The exercice of the session 48 of the course MIT 18.02 multivariate calculus, version 2010, obtainable [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02sc-multivariable-calculus-fall-2010/) reads as follows

[image: screenshot]

**My question**:

While I get the derivation and computation, what I'm failing to understand is how to spontaneously come up with the very first equation: 
$$
z = 1 - x - y
$$
indeed if we compute the edge of the tethrahedron in 2D at the base (by looking at the first drawing in the answer), it is easy to see and write: 
$$
y = 1-x
$$
However, from this point on, how do we include the variable height $z$ in the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps it is more natural to notice that the plane that contains $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, and $(0,0,1)$ is given by the equation $x+y+z=1$. If we solve this equation for $z$, we obtain $z=1-x-y$.